# Very simple translational invariant Hamiltonian and adaptation for physically sensible hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, group-theory, commutator

If we consider the Hamiltonian of a system as given by

$$H_0 = \hat{p}.\tag{1}$$

Then the unitary evolution operator will be given by

$$U(t) = \exp\left({-\frac{iH_0t}{\hbar}}\right)= \exp\left({-\frac{i\hat{p}t}{\hbar}}\right).\tag{2}$$

Then $U(t)$ is the generator of space translations by $t$, that is $$U(t)^\dagger V(x) U(t) = V(x+t).\tag{3}$$

This is useful for a perturbative solution of $H = H_0 + V$, since in the interaction picture:

$$V_I(x) = e^{+\frac{iH_0t}{\hbar}}V(x) e^{-\frac{iH_0t}{\hbar}}= V\left(x+\frac{t}{\hbar}\right)\tag{4}$$

and therefore the Dyson series solution becomes:

$$U(t,0) = \mathcal{T}\hspace{-1.9pt}\text{-}\hspace{-1pt}\exp\left\lbrace-i \int_0^tdt'V\left(x+\frac{t'}{\hbar}\right)\right\rbrace\tag{5}$$

but since $H_0 = \hat{p}$ is a unphysical hamiltonian, can one consider that:

for $\tilde{H}_0 = \frac{p^2}{2m}$ we have  $$U(t) = \exp\left({-\frac{i\tilde{H}_0t}{\hbar}}\right)= \exp\left({-\frac{ip^2t}{2m\hbar}}\right).\tag{6}$$

Then can one say that $$U(t)^\dagger V(x) U(t) =\exp\left({+\frac{ip^2t}{2m\hbar}}\right)V(x)\exp\left({-\frac{ip^2t}{2m\hbar}}\right)\stackrel{?}{=} V\left(x+\frac{pt}{2m\hbar}\right)~ ?\tag{7}$$

So that

$$U(t) = \exp\left({-\frac{ip^2t}{2m\hbar}}\right)=\exp\left({-ip\frac{pt}{2m\hbar}}\right) \tag{8}$$

still keeps being a generator of space translations?

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): There seems to be a factor 2 missing in OP's last formulas (7) & (8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H_0(\hat{p})$ is a function of the momentum operator, and $V(\hat{x})$ is a function of the position operator, then indeed the interaction picture becomes
$$\begin{align}\hat{V}_I~=~& \exp\left\{\frac{it}{\hbar}H_0(\hat{p})\right\}V(\hat{x})\exp\left\{-\frac{it}{\hbar}H_0(\hat{p})\right\}\cr
~=~& V\left(\exp\left\{\frac{it}{\hbar}H_0(\hat{p})\right\}\hat{x}\exp\left\{-\frac{it}{\hbar}H_0(\hat{p})\right\}\right)\cr
~=~& V\left(\exp\left\{\frac{it}{\hbar}[H_0(\hat{p}), \cdot]\right\}\hat{x}\right)\cr
~=~& V\left(\hat{x}+t H_0^{\prime}(\hat{p}) \right).\end{align}$$
Here the prime denotes a differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your claim is true. Intuitively, you just need to prove it for $V=x$. Since the interaction picture is obtained by conjugation, this property is immediately extended to any polynomial $V$. This usually suffices for most applications.

The case of $x$ is investigated by Heisenberg’s equations of motion:
$$
\begin{align}
i\hbar\dot V_I &=[V_I,H_0] \\
&= \frac{1}{2m}([V_I,p]p+p [V_I,p])
\end{align}
$$
Setting $V=x$, you do get:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot x_I &= \frac{p_I}{m\hbar}\\
x_I &= x+ \frac{pt}{m\hbar}
\end{align}
$$
I used the fact that $p_I=p$ since $[p,H_0]=0$.

Hope this helps.